# Exception thrown by throws will be caught?

Tags: java, exception

I have some doubts on throws keyword.
I will explain my through my example.

From Constructor I am calling do1() method and from do1() method I am calling do2() method.

Now do2() can throw checked exception "FileNotFoundException". So I declare and throw it to the called method.
And again Compiler asking me to handle in called method do2() and do2()'s called method constructor.After constructor(last called method) throws it, where exception will be handled if any exceptions occured like filepath not found in do2()?we just thrown it.we didn't catch it.thorwing itself is enough to handle exception.

```
public Parent() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Super");


    do1();


}
    void do1() throws FileNotFoundException{

        do2();
    }


void do2() throws FileNotFoundException{
     FileReader f=new FileReader("C:/as");
    }
```

Comment: You're not throwing any exceptions in the code above.

Comment: Robert: constructing FileReader may throw an exception...

Comment: The Exception is catched from the DefaultExceptionHandler.

Comment: *Caught* in the DefaultExceptionHandler.  And the default action of that handler is to end the application.

Comment: @HotLicks Not with `Exception` instances, you have to handle them. This would be true for `RuntimeException` instances though.

Comment: @Laf - You don't have to handle anything.  You can skip adding RuntimeException to your `throws` clause and your code will still compile, but RuntimeExceptions will still be propagated.  Eventually the default handler catches stuff not otherwise caught and brings down the app.

Comment: @HotLicks True ;) I overlooked the fact that you can add `throws` clause to the `main` method ;)

Comment: Heck, yes.  Half my little test cases have `throws java.io.IOException` on the `main` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The exception will have to be eventually handled somewhere, but it does not have to be in your `Parent` class. In your case, the method that calls `new Parent ()` might catch the exception, or throw it again to its calling method.

E.g.

```
try {
    Parent p = new Parent ();
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Or, you could have something like:

```
private Parent methodCreatingParent () throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new Parent ();
}

private void someOtherMethod () {
    try {
        Parent p = methodCreatingParent ();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

The `throws` keyword is used when a method that throws an exception (`Parent ()` in your case) does not have enough context information to handle the exception correctly.

#### Edit

As per @Hot Licks' comment, it can be possible to never handle the `FileNotFoundException`, using the following code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Parent p = new Parent ();
    }
}
```

In this case, the default exception handler would automatically handle the exception. The default handler prints the stack trace and stops the application. The handler to use can be specified via the method `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)`.

Answer (score -2):

you need  try catch block around your fileReader.  That is how you "catch" your errors.

```
try{
    FileReader f = new FileReader("C:/as");
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //handle exception
}
```

that is what you need.  Stating throws exception in method line, from my knowledge, is there so you as a programmer know what is being handled in the method.

Comment: The `throws` clause identifies what is *not* handled by the method.  For each checked exception that can originate in your method you must have either a `catch` statement or the corresponding `throws` clause.